# Hebbian learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, logic, neural-network

I have asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640755/how-to-utilize-hebbian-learning) on Hebbian learning before, and I guess I got a good answer which I accepted, but, the problem is that I now realize that I've mistaken about Hebbian learning completely, and that I'm a bit confused.

So, could you please explain how it can be useful, and what for? Because the way Wikipedia and some other pages describe it - it doesn't make sense! Why would we want to keep increasing the weight between the input and the output neuron if the fire together? What kind of problems can it be used to solve, because when I simulate it in my head, it certainly can't do the basic AND, OR, and other operations (say you initialize the weights at zero, the output neurons never fire, and the weights are never increased!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems rather theory-related, and I'm not sure if it belongs to SO, but since it is directly connected to neural networks, I'll try to answer.

We increase the weight between input and output neurons if they fire together because firing together means that they are somehow related.

Let's use the example of logic functions. In an `AND` function, you would have two input neurons. If your input data is `(0, 0)`, it means that neither input neuron fire, and neither will the output. So you don't need strong connections in this case.

Now take the input `(1, 1)`. Both input neurons fire, and so does the output. In order to learn this correspondence, the network should increase the weights connecting the input and output (remember, it is basically a matter of summing up the inputs and a bias neuron).

Finally, when the ouput is `(1, 0)` or `(0, 1)`, since the output is `0`, it tells the network that neither connection should be strong enough to activate the output neuron on its own.

I hope it makes sense.